# given that $a_n$ is an arithmetic sequence, and $a_{14}^2+a_{15}^2+a_{16}^2=35$, $a_{15} > 0$ find the general term of an $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I am right now in the Hebrew University Academic Prep School which in its level is equivalent to an American high school/college. It's a one-year academic prep school for engineering and exact science.

Due to the war in Israel right now, the academic year started a little bit later than usual. So far we have not learned much about arithmetic series, just the basics, including finding the general term of $a_n$, and finding the sum of $a_n$, (at even and odd places). I am including the formulas that we were taught so it can help you understand how to answer the question.

$S_n = \frac{(2a_1 + d(n-1))n}{2} = \frac{(a_1 + a_n)n}{2}$

$S_{2n_{even}} = \frac{(2a_2 + 2d(n-1))n}{2}$, $S_{2n_{odd}} = \frac{(2a_1 + 2d(n-1))n}{2}$

$S_{2n+1_{even}} = \frac{(2a_2 + 2d(n-1))n}{2}$, $S_{2n+1_{odd}} = \frac{(2a_1 + 2d(n))n}{2}$

$a_n = a_1 + d (n-1)$

$\begin{cases}
a_1 \\
a_{n+1} &= a_n + d
\end{cases}
$

### Question:

given that $a_n$ is an arithmetic sequence, and $$a_{14}^2+a_{15}^2+a_{16}^2=35$$ $$a_{15} > 0$$
find the **general term of an $a_n$**

It would be greatly appreciated if you could solve this with the basic equations as we don't really know much about series. Thank you so much.

Comment: An arithmetic sequence is constant or else diverges to $\pm \infty$.  This one can’t do the latter, or eventually $a_n^2 > 35$.  So it must be constant…

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further?

Comment: There are multiple such sequences, $a_{14}=0, d=\sqrt{7}$ or $a_{14}=\sqrt{35/3}, d=0$ work

Comment: or $a_{14}=1$, $d=2$;  Shalom

Comment: Does the question say that the sequence consists of integers? If so there is only one solution. The easiest way to do it is to set $a_{15} =a$ and the common difference = $d$. Then $a_{14}=a-d$ and $a_{15}=a+d$ so $(a-d)^2+a^2+(a+d)^2=35$

Comment: @MichaelCohen:  of course you meant $a_{1\color{red}6}=a+d$, but that’s essentially how I solved it

Comment: or $a_{14}=-3$, $d=4$

Comment: There are four integer solutions: $(-3, 4);\; (1,2);\; (5,-4);\;(5,-2)$

Answer (score 1):

Choose $a_{14} = A-B$, $a_{15}=A$ and $a_{16}=A+B$, where $A>0$ so that the given condition can be written as $$3A^2+2B^2=35$$ Now there’s multiple (infinite) pairs of $A$ and $B$ that can be chosen to satisfy this equation. Each of those would correspond to different arithmetic sequences.

However, if we look over the integers we can reduce this quite easily: it’s clear that $|A|<4$ and that $|B|<5$, so that $(A,B)$ is $(3,2)$ or $(3,-2)$ or $(1,4)$ or $(1,-4)$. In the first case we get that the arithmetic sequence can be described as $a_n = 2n-27$, for the second that $a_n = 33-2n$, in the third that $a_n = 4n -59$ and in the fourth that $a_n = 61-4n$ where $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $a_n$ denotes the $n$th term of the arithmetic sequence.

Comment: I wonder why the question specifies $a_{15}>0$